# Razor Page not showing foreign table data

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, razor-pages

I have a model class with two foreign keys and their respective navigation properties. However, when loading this model class, the foreign table data not showing.

Following is the class code:

```
public class SquadPlayer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int SquadId { get; set; }

    public int PlayerId { get; set; }

    public Squad Squad { get; set; }

    public Player Player { get; set; }
}
```

Back-end .cs code

```
public async Task OnGetAsync()
{
    SquadPlayer = await _context.SquadPlayers.ToListAsync();
}
```

Display .cshtml code

```
<td>
       @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Squad.Name)
</td>
<td>
       @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Player.Name)
</td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update this code:

```
public async Task OnGetAsync()
{ 
    SquadPlayer = await _context.SquadPlayers.ToListAsync(); 
}
```

to:

```
public async Task OnGetAsync()
{ 
    SquadPlayer = await _context.SquadPlayers
                                .Include(x => x.Squad)
                                .Include(x => x.Player).ToListAsync(); 
}
```

Comment: worked as expected. Thanks. I tried using include but was confused about syntax.

Comment: For `.Include`, you can string as many as you want, and they string off of the original *SquadPlayers*. If you need to do an include off of *Squad* or *Player* for example, then you can do a `.ThenInclude()` off of *Squad* or *Player*.